# Outlier removal before or after Kalman filtering?

Tags: design-patterns, cluster-analysis, k-means, pattern-recognition, kalman-filter

I am getting radar data points in form of (x,y) coordinate system relative to my position every ms.[around 10-15 data points]. Now, inorder to have better position estimate of the points, I would like to apply Kalman filter.

I also would like to further apply highpass filter to data in frequency domain. At what stage is it optimal to apply kalman filtering (before or after outlier removal and highpass filtering)?

Thank you very much for your response and please do let me know if further information is required.

P.S: I plan to apply kmean clustering to detect the outliers.

Comment: k-means is quite sensitive to outliers. Use something more advanced, like LOF.

Comment: It's best to remove outliers before filtering. Kalman filtering is a variety of least squares and passing in outliers will pollute your state estimates. It's also possible to detect (and reject) the outliers in the filter itself. Look for Local Slippage Test and w-statistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *outliers* have no information (they are known bad readings), then it would be best to remove them before the filter.  You can even remove them inside the filter if `y[i]` exceeds some threshold.  If outliers have some information, but known high noise, you can reflect that by adjusting `R` with the actual high variance for that specific measurement.  That will cause that measurement to have less influence on the result.